# Policy of AudioPlaybackCapture API not work

Tags: android, audio-recording, playback

As listed with  AudioPlaybackCapture API [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture#disabling_system_capture)
to prevent capture of audio by third party apps and system apps we should

> set the capture policy to ALLOW_CAPTURE_BY_NONE.

but system app was able to record audio.

## Update 1

tried add `android:allowAudioPlaybackCaputure="false"` but did not solve problem

## Update 2

tried change audio attributes

```
   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setAllowedCapturePolicy(ALLOW_CAPTURE_BY_NONE)
                .setUsage(USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
                .build().also {
                    videoController.player?.audioComponent?.setAudioAttributes(it, true)
                }
```

but did not solve problem

Comment: That's interesting. Was now trying to understand something to do with that. Please come here: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml. Go to CAPTURE_MEDIA_OUTPUT and CAPTURE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION_OUTPUT. If you take a look on those, they talk about the ALLOW_CAPTURE_BY_NONE restriction. Intersting enough, if you now take a look on CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT, they don't talk about that there. I'm supposing it might be that - you might also be kind of confirming that they can still record. Just don't know if this with this permission or not.

Comment: the code above was `set` before player is totally prepared/initialized. 
when i move it after preparing player, code runs fine

Comment: Oh. Then they actually can't. Cool. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2** works, but **must** be added after initialize player.

Answer (score 0):

i try this

```
AudioManager.setAllowedCapturePolicy(ALLOW_CAPTURE_BY_NONE)
```

in oppo reno 6 ,
This does not work to block system audio captured by the system application